# Getting Client IP Address & Session ID on OSGi Eclipse Jetty v9.2

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, osgi, embedded-jetty

I have recently followed the guide written by Peter Friese [here](http://www.peterfriese.de/osgi-servlets-a-happy-marriage/) and I am glad that it is all working fine.

However, I am having trouble accessing information via the HttpServletRequest object when a POST request comes in via a client request.

Typically, I would access the session ID via

```
request.getSession().getId()
```

and access the client IP address via

```
request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for")
```

OR

```
request.getRemoteAddr()
```

Now, in Jetty, these pieces of information are coming in as empty strings, and that is stumping me a bit.

I'm running my bundles in a local Apache Karaf instance, with the 'war' and 'http' features installed. POST requests are made from a REST utility on the same machine to

```
 http://127.0.0.1:<port>/<alias>/<path>
```

Does anyone have a clue on how I should be retrieving this information?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've now managed to get the SessionID via

```
 String sessionID = request.getSession(true).getId();
```

Now all that is left is the IP address.

Comment: ever considered in using InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()??